# TS1005 Javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito hacer un FormData y para eso estoy usando los mismo nombres que tengo en un formulario externo para los id. Algunos ID son combinaciones de numeros y letras como por ejemplo este `00N5f00000jUpUOl`. Ésto no genera un error pero sí un warning.

> TS1005: (JS) ':' expected

> TS1005: (JS) ';' expected

```
    var formData = {
        firs_name: ('#first_name').val(),
        last_name: ('#last_name').val(),
        mobile: ('#mobile'),
        email: ("#email"),
        company: ('#company'),
        00N5f00000jUpUOl: ('#00N5f00000jUpUOl'),
        street: ('#street'),
        city: ('#city'),
    }
```

Existe alguna forma para evitar éste warning? No quiero esperar a tener futuros problemas

Comment: Si esto es jQuery, me parece que te falta el $ al principio y el val() al final, ejemplo: $('#mobile').val();

Comment: De hecho lo estaba tratando de hacer de forma nativa. con JQuery, si hago `$('#mobile').val` tengo este warning: `TS1003: (JS) Identifier expected`.

Comment: Prueba quitando la coma al final de city, y también evita usar números al inicio para definir nombres, es una mala práctica. En vez de `00N5f00000jUpUOl` que tal `n5f00000jUpUOl`? No estoy muy familiarizado con Jquery, nunca lo he usado. [Referencia](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)

Comment: Claro, lo quise probar asi, sin los numeros al inicio, pero el formulario no lo hice yo, ni hice los endpoints, y quería respetar los id con los que deberían llegar al formulario externo. Si no pongo lo `00` al inicio, me lo tomará el form?

Comment: Es que esto ("#email") es lo mismo que "#email", es decir mandas un string que dice "#email". Entonces lo primero es que arregles el código, porque francamente no tiene sentido alguno y partamos de ahí para corregir los errores que te salen. Además incluye el método con que haces la llamada